# Windows 8 and Ninject : Reflection method cannot be used on the current platform

Tags: reflection, dependency-injection, windows-runtime, ninject

I have a windows 8 app solution and I am using MVVM. So I have the viewModelLocator and that does it's job.

But now I also want ninject to do some dependency injection (since the viewModelLocator is actually a locator, but no DI)

So I went to download the ninject DLL for .net framework 4.5 and try to get an instance of a type from the kernel like this:

```
DataSource = NinjectKernel.Get<IBudgetTrackerAppDataSource>();
```

Where the DataSource is a class used throughout the whole app. The problem is when that line is executed, I get the following error:

```
The API 'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParentDefinition()' cannot be used on the current platform
```

So I think Ninject and Windows 8 are having a fight, so the question is: How can I get past this issue? (Another version of ninject? another DI framework? ...)

Comment: Windows 8 Desktop app or WinRT?

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to mention, WinRT
And reading your name, I have seen the unreleased version that you pointed out that should be working with WinRT, but to be honest I don't know where to start to build it :-)

Comment: I thought of removing the tags from your title, but that would render an empty title. You really should think of a better title that highlights your problem, not just words with hyphens between them.

Comment: well, there, title changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build WinRT apps you can only reference other WinRT assemblies, this is why referencing a .NET 4.5 version of Ninject won't work correctly. It does appear there is a WinRT version of Ninject but it hasn't been released, the source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/remogloor/ninject).

There are a number of IoC frameworks that support WinRT out there. Both Caliburn.Micro and MVVM Light come with there own containers as well as [MetroIoC](http://metroioc.codeplex.com/).